# Updating node properites with py2neo doesn't work with remote server

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I have a node in my Neo4j database, which I retrieve using the find_one() method of the py2neo interface.

```
profile = graph.find_one('Facebook','fb_id', fb_id)
profile['nb_friends'] = nb_friends  # a list of posts
profile.push()
```

The above statement works fine when updating the local Neo4j database, but not when using a remote Neo4j server (nothing is changed).

However, if I run a raw Cypher query it works both locally and remotely.

```
graph.cypher.execute('MATCH (n:Facebook {fb_id:{ID}}) SET n.nb_friends = {FR} RETURN n',{'ID':fb_id,'FR':nb_friends})
```

Any idea why this happens and how it could be fixed?

*Note: the only modification I've done to the server configuration is to disable authentification.*

Answer (score 0):

I would be surprised if the local/remote aspect is directly significant here. Py2neo does not know or care where the server is located and does not take a different code path for localhost.

I'd suggest making sure that you are using the same version on both servers, that your connection URIs both have the same path (which should end in a trailing slash) and that the data is similar on both.

You may have also hit this bug:
https://github.com/nigelsmall/py2neo/issues/395

Empty lists are not supported as property values and py2neo has a bug that makes `push` fail silently when this is attempted. An exception will be raised for this in the next release.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Neo4j 2.2.0 both locally and remotely, and py2neo 2.0.6. I do havea trailing forward slash at the end of my URI, and I was using the same test samples. In my for-loop, I do have empty values, but I checked a case for a non-empty string (and I checked the control flow to make sure it got to that statement). I'll check the http logs tomorrow to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I was having a similar issue with py2neo 3 (graph.push() was failing silently). It turns out that I using an old version of Neo4j (2.1.7) which I had installed on accident. Try downloading a newer version and trying again.